# Ajax retrieving errors not working Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

I'm trying to retrieve errors when a user fills a form submitted using ajax. I'm following this [tutorial](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-ajax-request-validation-exampleexample.html). I'm not getting the result expected despite the logic I think should be right.
Here is my blade view code :

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('title','Soumettre thématique')
@section('content')
<body>

<div class="container_fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display: none;">
@if($errors->any())
<ol style="color: red">
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
<li>
  {{$error}}
</li>
@endforeach
</ol>
@endif
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <form method="POST" action=" {{route('themes.store')}} ">
        @csrf
        <!-- Intitulé du thème -->
        <input type="text" name="intitule" id="intitule" placeholder="Intitulé du thème" required><br>
        <!-- Catégorie -->
        <select name="categorie" required>
            <option value="">-- Catégorie --</option>
            <option value="web">Développement web</option>
            <option value="appMobile">Programmation application mobile</option>
            <option value="secure">Sécurisation</option>
            <option value="other">Autre</option>
        </select> <br>
        <!-- Filière désirée -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="GL" value="GL" required>
        <label for="GL">Génie Logiciel</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="SI" value="SI" required>
        <label for="SI">Sécurité Informatique</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="IM" value="IM" required>
        <label for="IM">Internet et Multimédia</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filiere[]" id="SIRI" value="SIRI" required>
        <label for="SIRI">Systèmes d'Information et Réseaux Informatiques</label><br>
        <!-- Descriptif -->
        <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description de la thématique" required>{{old('description')}} </textarea><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Ajouter">
        <span id="error-message" class="text-danger"></span>
        <span id="success-message" class="text-success"></span>
    </form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function (){
            var itsChecked = null;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){
                if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){ //S'il y a au moins 1 ([...].length > 0) ckecked
                // alert('At least one is checked');
                    $('#GL').removeAttr("required");
                    $('#SI').removeAttr("required");
                    $('#IM').removeAttr("required");
                    $('#SIRI').removeAttr("required");
                }
                else if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){ //S'il n'y a aucun checked (!(at least 1)>0)
                // alert('None is checked');
                    $('#GL').attr('required','');
                    $('#SI').attr('required','');
                    $('#IM').attr('required','');
                    $('#SIRI').attr('required','');

            }
            });

            $('#submit').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
                var intitule = $("input[name='intitule']").val();
                var categorie = $("select[name='categorie']").val();
                var filiereChecked = [];
                $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function(){            
                filiereChecked.push($(this).val());
                });
                var filiere = filiereChecked.join(", ");
                var filiere = filiere.toString();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('themes.store')}}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        _token:_token,
                        intitule:intitule,
                        categorie:categorie,
                        filiere:filiere
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                            alert(data.success);
                        }
                        else{
                            // console.log(data.error);
                            printErrorMsg(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        function printErrorMsg (msg) {

            $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');

            $(".print-error-msg").css('display','block');

            $.each( msg, function( key, value ) {

                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>'+value+'</li>');

            });

        }

        });
    </script>
</body>
@endsection
```

The controller store function :

```
 /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'intitule' => 'unique:themes,intitule'
        ]);
        $theme = new Theme;
        $theme->intitule = $request->input('intitule');
        $theme->description = $request->input('description');
        $theme->categorie = $request->input('categorie');
        $request->merge([
            'filiere' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('filiere'))
        ]);
        $theme->filiereDesiree = $request->input('filiere');
        $theme->save();

        if ($validator->passes()) {


            return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records.']);

        }


        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);

   }
```

The problem is I'm not getting a message at all, either success or error may it be. I don't know where I'm doing wrong there.

P.S: 
I've already used Ajax to submit this form. I did it using XMLHttpRequest object. The problem was I do not know how to use the 422 status to return errors using this XHR object. I've looked for it but found nothing really helpful.. So I changed this method to use here the ajax() jquery function which seems to be more used. Still not getting the messages.. It's the first time I try to manage the validation errors using Ajax. Your help would be very welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) for your validation.

```
php artisan make:request ThemeCreateRequest
```

Controller

```
use App\Http\Request\ThemeCreateRequest

 public function store(ThemeCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $theme = new Theme;
        $theme->intitule = $request->input('intitule');
        $theme->description = $request->input('description');
        $theme->categorie = $request->input('categorie');
        $request->merge([
            'filiere' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('filiere'))
        ]);
        $theme->filiereDesiree = $request->input('filiere');
        $theme->save();

        if ($validator->passes()) {


            return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records.']);

        }


        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);

   }
```

App\Http\Request\ThemeCreateRequest.php

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'intitule' => 'required|unique',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't it be ```public function store(ThemeCreateRequest $request)```?.. I've just tried it, still no message returned

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on your controller.

```
return response()->json(array('errors'=>$validator->getMessageBag()->toArray(),));
```

and in javascript try to use this one

```
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.error){
                            printErrorMsg(data.error);
                        }
                        else{
                            alert(data.success);
                        }
                    }
```

ajax code

```
                   $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('themes.store')}}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        _token:_token,
                        intitule:intitule,
                        categorie:categorie,
                        filiere:filiere
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.error){
                            printErrorMsg(data.error);
                        }
                        else{
                            alert(data.success);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'intitule' => 'unique:themes,intitule'
        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {
           return response()->json(array('error'=>$validator->getMessageBag()->toArray(),));
        }
        $theme = new Theme;
        $theme->intitule = $request->input('intitule');
        $theme->description = $request->input('description');
        $theme->categorie = $request->input('categorie');
        $request->merge([
            'filiere' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('filiere'))
        ]);
        $theme->filiereDesiree = $request->input('filiere');
        $theme->save();

        return response()->json(array('success'=>'Added new records.',));
       }
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but I'm still getting no message.. Should I tell something about the content type the server should return? I'm talking about this line of code ```header("Content-Type: text/json");```. I wrote it but don't know if this may be the problem because I still don't understand why it is not working..

Comment: are you sure that your click event is working? the return that i put is already a object and ajax data need to be an json/object. Maybe you're experiencing other error? Sorry but i dont know what is the use of `header("Content-Type: text/json");` but im not using that and i get an error message and success message.

Comment: yes you're right, without it, it still works. I've resolved my problem, it was an error in my view. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Oops this is my fault... I've just figured why it was not working. I've placed this in my blade view

```
@if($errors->any())
<ol style="color: red">
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
<li>
  {{$error}}
</li>
@endforeach
</ol>
@endif
```

instead of the `<ul> </ul>` tags that the javascript code is looking for to output the errors. Thank you all